# How to create key value pair window to add dynamic properties in mule custom connector , currently using mule 3

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I tried adding map as parameter to the connector class method definition , but not able to see key value pair window in mule flow UI properties

Comment: Please provide more details about the issue, share the code that you have, describe better what is the "key value pair windows". Kindly read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to improve your question.

Comment: For each component we have general settings where we have few options for modifying settings , instead of drop down or radio button , is there any option where can dynamically input both label and its value like a key value pair

Comment: What components? Are you developing a custom connector with DevKit? please provide more details and source snippets to illustrate.

Comment: Sorry company code will not be able to display ..yes custom connector using devkit

Comment: If you can't display company code, make a reproduction. It's fine to take some time and make an effort for people to understand your actual issue. If you are not willing to provide this, I don't see why people will bother helping you here. I voted for closing. Also, if you have any update, make them in your question and not in the comments.

Comment: The thing is @kissu , my company has blocked this website so I'm typing all my queries from my phone  to reproduce , definitely will do that but if you vote for closing then how can I do ..?

Comment: If you can not copy the actual code you can make at least an attempt to show a simplified example to illustrate the data types without using actual names. For the record I answer many questions from the phone, sometimes with simple code examples ;-)

Comment: @aled idk how you can achieve code snippets from the phone: having to write 5 lines of properly formatted JS is a nightmare (in my daily routine).

Comment: Agreed. It works for simple examples of one or two lines without much formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If it is supported at all it is something like the following but I can't test it:

```
class Operations {
...
@Processor
    public void someOperation(String a, Map<String, Object> headers)
...
}
```

Comment: That's Config class , but in Connector class there is a method for each operation annotated by @processor , I'm trying to include linkedhashmap as parameter to the method but I'm getting an error telling "Could not find a transformer to transform simpledatatype hashmap to linkedhashmap" is there any other alternative to preserve the order in map if linkedhashmap isn't working

Comment: I'll update my answer but that information should be in the question actually. Where are you getting the error, at build time, design time (in Studio) or execution time (in Mule)?